# SpecFlow test session doesn't start if I try to load plugin

Tags: c#, mstest, specflow

I added this block in my app.config:

```
  <specFlow>
        <unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />
    <plugins>
      <add name="Test" path=".\plugins" type="Runtime"/>
    </plugins>
  </specFlow>
```

Direcory is empty. And now when I try to run or debug my SpecFlow tests - session fails with this mesage `The program '[13092] vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

Comment: highlight the error code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem will be that you have not specified the actual dll that your plugin code is in, just the directory.

I think you need something more like this:

```
<specFlow>
      <unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />
  <plugins>
    <add name="Test" path=".\plugins\MyPlugin.dll" type="Runtime"/>
  </plugins>
</specFlow>
```